# Writing data to a cell in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to write information on an Excel sheet. I already have the following code to write the word "date" to cell `A1`:

```
sheet.Range("A1").value = "date"
```

What's the best way to check if there's no previous information in the cell before writing?

For example, if there's something already written in cell `A1`, then this new information should be written in the cell below `A2`. If there's information in that cell too, then move to `A3`, and so on...

How can this be done in vb.net?

Comment: just shift everything in column down using `sheet.Range("A1").insert xlshiftdown` then put the data in A1.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for the reply ok then i'm gonna give it a try , thanks a lot